# Firebase Multi-Page Signin

Tags: database, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, account

Hello Stackoverflow Community!

I have a pretty simple question that I am pretty sure there is an answer for!

I want to create a simple sign in system for a website, however, I am wondering whether or not I can login, and then carry over the fact that it is logged in to other pages on the site. Because once a user is logged into the site using signInWithEmailAndPassword(), and I want make sure they can navigate the full website and all of it's seperate html file pages, and stay signed in.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication is persisted between page loads. But instead of calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` on each page, you should [monitor `onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and then only call sign-in when there is no current user.